# Error on Update Join

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I'm receiving this error

This is my Current error: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword

```
UPDATE FGMULTI (JOIN arinvt ar 
 ON  fgmulti.arinvt_id = ar.id)

 SET NON_CONFORM_ALLOCATABLE = 'Y'

 WHERE IN_Date = CurrentDate 
  AND ar.Class LIKE 'CP%' 
  (OR ar.Class LIKE 'FG%' 
  OR ar.Class LIKE 'IN%' 
  OR ar.Class LIKE 'LA%' 
  OR ar.Class LIKE 'PK%')
```

Comment: You need to post your code or we can't help you.

Comment: The next time provide post your code i have post an answer anyway ..

Comment: Also, next time you post code - don't do it in a picture.  actually copy / paste the query or code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use update for select by join

```
 UPDATE (select NON_CONFORM_ALLOCTABLE
         from FGMULTI 
          JOIN arinvt ar 
          ON  fgmulti.arinvt_id = ar.id 
         WHERE IN_Date = CurrentDate 
         AND ar.Class LIKE 'CP%' 
         OR ar.Class LIKE 'FG%' 
         OR ar.Class LIKE 'IN%' 
         OR ar.Class LIKE 'LA%' 
         OR ar.Class LIKE 'PK%') t
 SET t.NON_CONFORM_ALLOCATABLE = 'Y'
```

Comment: I have look at you ìr comment code and you have other error (on in the wrong place ) i have update the asnwer and if this is right please mark it as accepted ..

Comment: I haven't see the LEFT OUTER join ...then the LEFT OUTER JOIN don't work but a simply join yes .. i have update the answer

Comment: Please .. if the answer that i have provided produced error or a wrong result showm the the error or the wrong result ..not comment with new sql command in can't understand what you are doing ..without proper explaination

Comment: THAT WAS IT!  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `JOIN` in Oracle in an UPDATE statement. You can do that using and `exists` clause:

```
UPDATE FGMULTI
   SET NON_CONFORM_ALLOCATABLE = 'Y'
 WHERE IN_Date = CurrentDate 
  AND exists (SELECT 1 
              FROM arinvt ar 
              WHERE fgmulti.arinvt_id = ar.id
               AND (ar.Class LIKE 'CP%' 
                 OR ar.Class LIKE 'FG%' 
                 OR ar.Class LIKE 'IN%' 
                 OR ar.Class LIKE 'LA%' 
                 OR ar.Class LIKE 'PK%'));
```